# Drush does not run remotely, SSH does not see Drush

Tags: drush

I had Drush 4. 
Then I deleted Drush folder and installed Drush 8 through Composer for my user.
Now `drush` command works on a server for my user.

Then I try to invoke drush from my local computer it does not work:

```
drush @myalias status -v
Loaded alias @myalias from file /home/myuser/.drush/site-aliases/aliases.drushrc.php                                                                                                           [notice]
Begin redispatch via drush_invoke_process().                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Calling proc_open(ssh myserver 'env COLUMNS=199 drush  --verbose --uri=my.site.com --root=/my/web/path  core-status 2>&1' 2>&1);
env: drush: No such file or directory
End redispatch via drush_invoke_process().
```

So I localized the problem - Drush does not work through SSH, but it works on the server under the same user.

```
ssh myalias 'drush'
bash: drush: command not found
```

I tried  unsuccessfully:
Add `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` or  `PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` to 
`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

But it works:  `ssh myalias  '~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush'`

Comment: Drush 4 is totally unsuported , why do you use it?

Comment: It is legacy.
It is a reason why I want updating.

Comment: Try `ssh myalias 'echo $PATH'` to confirm that the path is still incorrect. Then check that you are modifying PATH in the correct files. And this isn't a Drush question - it's all about your shell.